# Java - How to get the Scale that fits on given rectangle

Tags: java

I have A Paint method in java that Draws a Rectangle Randomly but my problem is that I want to find the perfect algorithm/formula that will fit the picture inside that Rectangle.

Comment: Please add more information. Make a small yet complete example of your  `Rectangle` class (if you have one), and how you are randomly generating rectangles. Also, specify what you have tried.

Comment: deadlydragon got it right. The question is quit simple for those Math expert and I also appreciate your participation Mr. @E_net4.

Comment: I understand your point, but in SO, members are often more concerned about programming language specifications and technologies than mathematical formulas for solving a problem. This is why you have received the down-votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometry formula
scale = min( container.width/picture.width , container.height/picture.height );

The Scale will be multiplied to the picture.

Comment: Wow Exactly what I need, Thumbs Up :)